# Cannot print '1'?

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and I was doing an exercise in school. For my following program where I am stuck:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main() {
 int n;
printf("Input the integer number:");
scanf("%d",&n);
int usevar=n;
int count=0;
while(n>1)
{
    n/=10;
    count++;
}
 int sum=0;
 printf("Reverse:\n");
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
{
    int a=pow(10,i);
    int b=pow(10,i-1);
    sum=(usevar%a-usevar%b)/b;
    printf("i=%d\n",sum);
}
  return 0;
}
```

When I inserted some int number such as `12345` the output should be:

Reverse:

```
i=5

i=4

i=3

i=2

i=1
```

But the output of my program is:

Reverse:

```
i=5

i=4

i=3

i=2
```

But when I input the number without '1' as start number, my program works correctly:

Input the integer number:23556

Reverse:

```
i=6

i=5

i=5

i=3

i=2
```

So what's the problem with the number that start with '1'? Can anyone give me the suggestion? I'm glad if you can help.

Comment: try while(n>0). It should work

Comment: Why don't you try debugging?

Comment: Did you try even basic debugging?

Comment: Because `while(n>1)`. It takes only numbers bigger (>) than 1. Try putting `while(n>0)`

Comment: Voting to close this question.

Comment: as stated by @BakhtiarHasan, you have a logical error. It would fail for any input whose first digit is 1. Try fixing that.

Comment: @Abhineet  for what?

Comment: Since the user is new to the forum as well as to programming, I personally believe we should not downvote this question. Instead the experienced people in the community should guide the user. Getting downvotes is highly demotivating. Whereas getting right guidance is highly motivating. The purpose of being on this forum is to help each other.

Comment: @maxx777 we are no forum, but a Q&A site. Rules apply to all users equally.

Comment: @Treycos: Because OP didn't show any research or debugging effort from his/her side. We are here to help those who help themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main() {

int n;
printf("Input the integer number:");
scanf("%d",&n);

while(n > 0){
    int rev = n%10;
    n = n/10;
    printf("i = %d\n",rev);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This comes from your first loop. Try:

```
while(n >= 1)
{
    n/=10;
    count++;
}
```